# Adding Angular.js Modal gives Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-modal

So I have an application and it's working great (MEAN stack), and I'm adding in the `<script src="/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-1.3.3.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.3.3.min.js"></script>` so that I can use the **modal**.

The code will be below, but here are some explanations first. I've added `angular.module('loc8rApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);` in my angular app declaration. And then in the controller I properly injected it via `locationDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$modal', 'loc8rData'];`. I haven't declared an `ng-controller`anywhere in the html, so I'm not really sure what the problem may be.

Lastly, a copy of the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20locationDetailCtrl
```

Below are 4 blocks of code. The first two are `locationDetail.controller.js` and `locationDetail.view.html`, the others are the `app.js` (angular app.js) and `index.html`.

`locationDetail.controller.js`

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('loc8rApp')
        .controller('locationDetailCtrl', locationDetailCtrl);

    locationDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$modal', 'loc8rData'];
    function locationDetailCtrl($routeParams, $modal, loc8rData) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.locationid = $routeParams.locationid;

        loc8rData.locationById(vm.locationid)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.data = { location: data };
                vm.pageHeader = {
                    title: vm.data.location.name
                };
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });

        vm.popupReviewForm = function() {
            alert("Let's add a review!");
        };
    }

})();
```

`locationDetail.view.html`

```
<navigation></navigation>

<div class="container">
    <page-header content="vm.pageHeader"></page-header>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="rating" rating-stars rating="vm.data.location.rating"></p>
                        <p>{{ vm.data.location.address }}</p>
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h2 class="panel-title">Opening hours</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p ng-repeat="time in vm.data.location.openingTimes" ng-switch on="time.closed">
                                    {{ time.days }} :
                                    <span class="opening-time" ng-switch-when="true">closed</span>
                                    <span class="opening-time" ng-switch-default>{{ time.opening + " - " + time.closing }}</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h2 class="panel-title">Facilities</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span class="label label-warning label-facility" ng-repeat="facility in vm.data.location.facilities">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                    {{ facility }}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 location-map">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h2 class="panel-title">Location map</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{ vm.data.location.coords[1] }},{{ vm.data.location.coords[0] }}&amp;zoom=17&amp;size=400x350&amp;sensor=false&amp;markers={{ vm.data.location.coords[1] }},{{ vm.data.location.coords[0] }}&amp;scale=2" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary review-panel">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <a ng-click="vm.popupReviewForm()" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add review</a>
                                <h2 class="panel-title">Customer reviews</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body review-container">
                                <div class="review" ng-repeat="review in vm.data.location.reviews | orderBy:'createdOn':true">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="well well-sm review-header">
                                            <span class="rating" rating-stars rating="review.rating"></span>
                                            <span class="reviewAuthor">{{ review.author }}</span>
                                            <small class="reviewTimestamp">{{ review.createdOn | date : 'MMMM d yyyy' }}</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p ng-bind-html="review.reviewText | addHtmlLineBreaks"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">{{ vm.data.location.name }} is on Loc8r because it has accessible wifi and space to sit down with your laptop and get some work done.</p>
                <p>If you've been and you like it - or if you don't - please leave a review to help other people just like you.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <footer-generic></footer-generic>
</div>
```

`app.js` (angular app.js).

```
(function() {

    angular.module('loc8rApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: '/common/views/genericText.view.html',
                controller: 'aboutCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/location/:locationid', {
                templateUrl: '/locationDetail/locationDetail.view.html',
                controller: 'locationDetailCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }

    angular
        .module('loc8rApp')
        .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);

})();
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="loc8rApp">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0">
        <title>Loc8r</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body ng-view>
        <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/angular/loc8r.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/validation.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Click on the link the error generates. Will take you to angular errors site and give you an explanation. Also if use development version of angular will get more verbose error output and stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error tells you there is an unknown provider `$modalProvider`. That means you are injecting `$modal` and it isn't defined within the app.

The reason is that angular-ui-bootstrap now uses `$uib` prefix for services.

Try changing `$modal` to `$uibModal` and verify in angular-ui-bootstrap docs

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I changed `locationDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$modal', 'loc8rData'];` to `locationDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$uibModal', 'loc8rData'];` and it then worked. That's interesting, thanks!

Comment: Yeah...that change confused me a few times also until it sunk into memory. Probably lots of examples out in the wild with old non `$uib` instnces